# gsub ) only if there is no (

Tags: r, regex

I am working in R and am trying to remove closing parenthesis only when there is no opening parenthesis. I have tried below and it is not returning the desired output.

```
test <- data.frame(t1 = c("Book (Pg 1)", "Website Online)", "Journal: 2018)"))
test

test$t2 <- ifelse(str_contains(test$t1, "("), test$t1, gsub("(", '', test$t1))
```

I am hoping to return test$t2 as "Book (Pg1)", "Website Online", "Journal: 2018"

Comment: You need to escape speical charaters with double backslash e.g., `'\\('`. See `?regex`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You accidentally used an open parenthesis (`"("`) instead of a close parenthesis (`")"`)** in your `gsub()`.  Also, since `(` and `)` are regex metacharacters, you need to **escape** them twice (once for R strings and once for regex) with a double backslash (`"\\"`).

Using the vectorized `grepl` as a `base` solution, we get:

```
test$t2 <- ifelse(grepl("\\(", test$t1), test$t1, gsub("\\)", "", test$t1))
```

which yields the following output for `test`:

```
               t1             t2
1     Book (Pg 1)    Book (Pg 1)
2 Website Online) Website Online
3  Journal: 2018)  Journal: 2018
```

Comment: for some reason its giving me "1" where it should be "Book (Pg 1)"

Comment: Did you reset `test` via  `test <- data.frame(t1 = c("Book (Pg 1)", "Website Online)", "Journal: 2018)"))`, all before running `test$t2 <- ifelse(grepl("\\(", test$t1), test$t1, gsub("\\)", "", test$t1))`?  Notice I'm using `grepl()` instead of `str_contains()`.

Comment: Yes, for some reason the type of test$t1 was set to integer so I changed it to as.character(test$t1) and got it to work. Thanks for your solution!

Comment: Happy to help!  :)

Answer (score 3):

You could also do:

```
sub("([(].*[)])|[)]", '\\1', test$t1)
[1] "Book (Pg 1)"    "Website Online" "Journal: 2018"
```

Comment: Mr. Onyambu may I ask why this `str_detect(c("(Website Online"), "[()]")` returns `TRUE` but if I separate every parenthesis in a bracket like you did it would return `FALSE`? I would appreciate your response.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand. So for this purpose I need to brackets.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR. i don;t understand what you mean. Though, you should note that just putting `(` will not work unless you include `fixed = TRUE` that is because `(` is a metacharacter

Comment: I'm sorry there was a typo, I meant two brackets so this `str_detect(c("(Website Online"), "[(][)]")` returns `FALSE`. Even inside bracket do we need to escape methacharacters?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR why would you hsve `[(][)]` that means you are trying to detect for `()` in your string. But there is no `()` in your string. So it will return false

Comment: I understand now. So `[(][)]` means that both parentheses have to stick together with no other character between them like `()`. At first I thought if we have `(` and `)` in our string that are not necessarily like `()` it would also return TRUE, but I was wrong.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Yes thats right. You could also simply do `\\(\\)`. ie escaping both characters as they are metacharacters. To learn more about regex meaning , please check wikipedia page on regex

Comment: Thank you for the great suggestion. I will check it out.

Comment: @Onyambu, can you please explain the regex I was trying `gsub('(\\(.*\\))', '\\1', test$t1, perl = T)` for hours was not working whilst you put `|` after first capture group and that worked?

Comment: @AnilGoyal your regex is simply capturung everything from (upto ) then replacing that part with the captured group. Nothing happens to the ) since its not even matched. Hence you will get exactly the same output as the input.

Comment: yes, Got it later-on.  Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 3):

**Updated Solution**
Thanks to a great tip from dear @r2evens, we could use the following solution to spare `rowwise` to have a more efficient solution:

```
test %>%
  mutate(t1 = if_else(grepl("\\(.*\\)", t1), t1, gsub("\\)", "", t1)))

              t1
1    Book (Pg 1)
2 Website Online
3  Journal: 2018
```

**Original solution**
You can also use the following solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

test %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(t1 = case_when(
    all(str_detect(t1, c("\\(", "\\)"))) ~ t1,
    TRUE ~ str_replace(t1, "\\)", "")
  ))

# A tibble: 3 x 1
# Rowwise: 
  t1            
  <chr>         
1 Book (Pg 1)   
2 Website Online
3 Journal: 2018
```

Comment: `rowwise()` is an unnecessary anti-efficiency here, and it is only necessary because of the regex you're using. Replace `all(... c("\\(","\\)"))` with `str_detect(t1, "\\(.*\\)")` and the rowwise requirement goes away. (And frankly, `stringr` and `case_when` add nothing here, this can be shorter with `mutate(test, t2 = if_else(grepl("\\(.*\\)", t1), t1, gsub("\\)", "", t1)))` (or just `grepl("\\(", t1)` for the condition).

Comment: Thank you dear @r2evans for the helpful tip. At first I tried to remove `rowwise` but it didn't lead to the desired result. So I would be glad to know why with my original regex we need it. As for the choice of `case_when` it only improves readability here but I will modify here. Thanks indeed.

Comment: You need `rowwise` because you use `all`, which is only necessary because you're checking `t1` against multiple patterns. Reducing that to a single pattern means you won't need `all`, and you can then remove `rowwise`. Since your two patterns are literals (not complex regex), combining them is straight-forward.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was very helpful. I've been struggling with a similar issue like this yesterday, as soon as I formulate my question I will be glad if you could help me with it.

Comment: Dear @r2evans I have a very quick question in the following code `sub("([(].*[)])|[)]", '\\1', test$t1)` that we created one captured group and separate it with `|` from another pattern if in the replacement arg we only specify `\\1` what would replace the second pattern that lies on the RHS of `|` ? is it just omitted? thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The LHS of the `|` is the pattern we want to keep, so there's the `\\1`; the RHS of the pattern we want to remove, so it is not included in the `\\1`. I think. Have you found strings where this pattern does not work?

Comment: Thank you very much. No it works very well but I just didn't know how it will realize to practically delete the second match (I mean LHS of | )? At first I thought it is as if we replace both matches with `\\1` so I was utterly confused.

Comment: The intent is to preserve the LHS of the `|` and discard the right; if the LHS is found, the the RHS is not used in this. If the LHS is not found and the RHS *is*, then the RHS is discarded. I think `"([(].*[)])","\\1"` is clear, this is a regex-noop, now to that we're appending `|[)]` which is outside of the capturing-parens, so `\\1` is empty if LHS is not found but RHS is.

Comment: Thank you very much dear @r2evans for your thorough explanations. It's very tricky but I understand it now.